# Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the below regex in JavaScript for password policy check:

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$_])(?=.*[\d\W]).*$
```

I tried the above regex using online regex checker
http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp

Test cases passed as expected, negative test cases failed. But same regex when deployed in application does not validate properly.

For eg:
`Tracker@123` does not work, where `tRacker@123` works
`Asd56544#12` also works fine.

Can you please point out what's wrong in regex above?

Comment: um, all 3 of your test cases pass for me (as they should). Can you post your code that says it's failing?

Comment: It seems to work, maybe the problem is in the way you use it

Comment: what's the point in the leading `.*` or the last group `(?=.*[\d\W])`? (not that it's your problem)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to separate this regex into several simple regex'es.
You may assign rules for your password, and for every rule you can assign a regex.

For example

1. Rule №1. Minimal length of password = 8 characters (can be done without regex)
2. Rule №2. At least one digit is required. ( `/[0-9]/` )
3. Rule №3. At least one letter is required ( `/[a-z]/i`)
4. Rule №4. Illegal characters for password ( regex for some characters you don't want users to use in passwords)
5. Rule №n - some little regex

*(and so on)*

With this approach, it will be more easier to manage your validation in sooner time. For example after a year, you'll have to change your password policy. You'll forget what your big regex is meaning (and will spend a lot of time changing that big regex, or doing a new one). But with little separates regexes (meaning rules) you easily configure your password policy

Comment: Thanks all for your hints and responses. I removed the last part (?=.*[\d\W]) and things started working fine. Why is that i should not sepcify \d or \W ?

Comment: 2 user632323: What did you want to do by adding (?=.*[\d\W]) ? It means "any symbols before a digit or not a word"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you syntax is correct?

Have a look at this JSfiddle, in it all the test cases pass

http://jsfiddle.net/pCLpX/